# Entity Framework - Version Property Name

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, entity

I'm searching for getting concurrency fixed property name at runtime through ObjectContext but I don't find any property or method able to give me this information.

Is there some way in order to get entity property name setted with "concurrencyMode=fixed"?

Comment: I think this thread contains the answer to your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732161/how-to-automate-setting-concurrencymode-fixed-on-all-rowversion-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of these properties by querying the conceptual model:

```
context.MetadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.CSpace)
    .OfType<EntityType>()
    .SelectMany(entityType => entityType.Properties)
    .OfType<EdmProperty>()
    .Where(ep => ep.TypeUsage.Facets.Any(f => f.Name == "ConcurrencyMode" 
            && (EdmConcurrencyMode)f.Value == EdmConcurrencyMode.Fixed))
    .Select(ep => new 
                    { 
                        Type = ep.DeclaringType.Name,
                        Property = ep.Name,
                        DateType = ep.TypeUsage.EdmType.Name 
                    })
```