# EF6 - How to assert at runtime which columns have Concurrency mode = fixed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In the Entity Framework Edmx editor (e.g. EF6), sometimes developers will completely delete an entity (table) and then re-import it (DB to C# model).  This often has the side effect of dropping properties that were manually set on columns such as Concurrency = fixed.

Is there a way to add a runtime check that can inspect such properties to verify they still are set as originally designed?  Especially the Concurrency mode.

If no runtime check is possible, maybe then a compile time check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructed a Unit Test by modifying answer to similar question from @narayana (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21863827/538763).  Thanks to @jojess for link.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace CompanyName.UnitTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class EntityFreameworkDbTests
    {
        public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

        [TestMethod]
        public void VerifyEdmxConcurrencyColumns()
        {
            const int minExpectedEdmxPathCount = 65;

            // Expected Output:  List all columns in all edmx that set ConcurrencyMode = fixed
            //
            List<Tuple<string, string, string>> expected = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>
            {
                // EMDX, TableName, ColumnName
                Tuple.Create("TheFileName.edmx", "ActivityLog", "Successes"),
                Tuple.Create("TheFileName.edmx", "ActivityLog", "Fails")
            };

            // use top of source tree to include all edmx files
            string serverSourceDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

            string [] edmxPaths = Directory.GetFiles(serverSourceDir, "*.edmx", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            Assert.IsTrue(edmxPaths.Count() >= minExpectedEdmxPathCount, "Under the expected min count of edmx paths: Actual = {0}, Expected = {1}"
                .FormatExt(edmxPaths.Count(), minExpectedEdmxPathCount));

            List<Tuple<string, string, string>> actual = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();

            TestContext.WriteLine("All Actuals:");

            foreach (string edmxPath in edmxPaths)
            {
                XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(edmxPath);

                IEnumerable<XElement> concurrencyFixedColumns = xmlDoc.Descendants()
                    .Where(el => (string)el.Attribute("ConcurrencyMode") == "Fixed");

                foreach (XElement el in concurrencyFixedColumns)
                {
                    string value = el.Attribute("ConcurrencyMode")?.Value;                   //modified = true;

                    if (value != null)
                    {
                        string edmxFile = Path.GetFileName(edmxPath);
                        string tableName = (string)el.Parent.Attribute("Name"); 

                        actual.Add(Tuple.Create(edmxFile, tableName, (string)el.Attribute("Name")));
                        TestContext.WriteLine("\t{0},{1},{2}", edmxFile, tableName, el.Attribute("Name"));
                    }
                }
            }

            StringBuilder errors = new StringBuilder();

            actual.Except(expected).ToList().ForEach(edmxColumn =>
                errors.AppendLine("Actual but not expected: " + edmxColumn.Item1 + "," + edmxColumn.Item2 + "," + edmxColumn.Item3));

            expected.Except(actual).ToList().ForEach(edmxColumn =>
                errors.AppendLine("Expected but not actual: " + edmxColumn.Item1 + "," + edmxColumn.Item2 + "," + edmxColumn.Item3));

            Assert.AreEqual(0, errors.Length, "\n\nEF Concurrency=fixed columns:\n" + errors.ToString() + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do your own partial classes. All EF classes are partial out of the box so you can expand them with your own partial classes, so define your custom things in your partial classes, this way they would persist even if the generated partial class is deleted (and generated again)

UPDATE: as OP pointed out, there is no way to achieve this with partial classes.  However here is the same question with answers that do edmx file update programmatically. It might help you:

[How to automate setting ConcurrencyMode=Fixed on all RowVersion columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732161/how-to-automate-setting-concurrencymode-fixed-on-all-rowversion-columns)

Comment: The Concurency mode flag does not appear to be part of the class.  Adding the flag to the class manually would not help determine the state of the real EF6 flag (wherever that is stored).

Comment: You are right, no way to do this with partial classes. However here is the same question with answers that do edmx file update programmatically. It might help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732161/how-to-automate-setting-concurrencymode-fixed-on-all-rowversion-columns